# Size of encoded avro message without encoding it

Tags: c++, avro

Is there a way to get the size of the encoded avro message without actually encoding it?

I'm using Avro 1.8.1 for C++.

I'm used to google protocol buffers where you can call `ByteSize()` on a protobuf to get the encoded size, so it's something similar i'm looking for.

Since the message in essence is a raw struct I get that the size cannot be retrieved from the message itself, but perhaps there is a helper method that i'm not aware of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way around it unfortunately...

Here is an example showing how the size can be calculated by encoding the object:

```
MyAvroStruct obj;

avro::EncoderPtr encoder = avro::binaryEncoder();
std::auto_ptr<avro::OutputStream> out = avro::memoryOutputStream(1);
encoder->init(*out);
avro::encode(*encoder, obj);
out->flush();
uint32_t bufferSize = out->byteCount();
```

Comment: This is terrible for performance: The MemoryOutputStream [will issue a memory allocation on the heap for every single byte of the serialized message](https://github.com/apache/avro/blob/master/lang/c%2B%2B/impl/Stream.cc#L138). You are right, however, it's the best you can do with avro's provided classes.

Answer (score 1):

(Edit below shows a hacky way to shrink-to-fit an `OutputStream` after writing to it with a `BinaryEncoder`)

It's a shame that `avro::encode()` doesn't use `backup` on the `OutputStream` to free unused memory after encoding. [Martin G's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43868335/12345551) gives the best solution using only the tools avro provides, but it issues N memory allocations of 1 byte each if your serialized object is N bytes in size.

You could implement a custom `avro::OutputStream` that simply counts and discards all written bytes. This would get rid of the memory allocations. It's still not a great approach, as the actual encoder will have to "ask" for every single byte:

(Code untested, just for demonstration purposes)

```cpp
#include <avro/Encoder.hh>
#include <cstdint>

class ByteCountOutputStream : public avro::OutputStream {
public:
    size_t byteCount_ = 0;
    uint8_t dummyWriteLocation_;

    explicit ByteCountOutputStream() {};

    bool next(uint8_t **data, size_t *len) final {
        byteCount_ += 1;
        *data = &dummyWriteLocation_;
        *len = 1;
        return true;
    }

    void backup(size_t len) final {
        byteCount_ -= len;
    }

    uint64_t byteCount() const final {
        return byteCount_;
    }

    void flush() final {}
};
```

this could then be used as:

```cpp
MyAvroStruct obj;

avro::EncoderPtr encoder = avro::binaryEncoder();
ByteCountOutputStream out();
encoder->init(out);
avro::encode(*encoder, obj);
size_t bufferSize = out.byteCount();
```

---

Edit:
My initial question when stumbling upon this was: How can I tell how many bytes of the `OutputStream` are required (for storing / transmitting)? Or, equivalently, if `OutputStream.byteCount()` returns the count of bytes allocated by the encoder so far, how can I make the encoder "backup" / release the bytes it didn't use? Well, there is a hacky way:

The `Encoder` abstract class provides a [`init` method](https://github.com/apache/avro/blob/e828cb0adc3c24e970f47c181d39ba21350d2ab5/lang/c%2B%2B/api/Encoder.hh#L58). For the BinaryEncoder, this is [currently implemented as](https://github.com/apache/avro/blob/e828cb0adc3c24e970f47c181d39ba21350d2ab5/lang/c%2B%2B/impl/BinaryEncoder.cc#L58):

```cpp
void BinaryEncoder::init(OutputStream &os) {
    out_.reset(os);
}
```

with `out_` being the [internal `StreamWriter` of the Encoder](https://github.com/apache/avro/blob/e828cb0adc3c24e970f47c181d39ba21350d2ab5/lang/c%2B%2B/impl/BinaryEncoder.cc#L28).

Now, the `StreamWriter` [implements `reset` as](https://github.com/apache/avro/blob/e828cb0adc3c24e970f47c181d39ba21350d2ab5/lang/c%2B%2B/api/Stream.hh#L389):

```cpp
    void reset(OutputStream &os) {
        if (out_ != nullptr && end_ != next_) {
            out_->backup(end_ - next_);
        }
        out_ = &os;
        next_ = end_;
    }
```

which will return unused memory back to the "old" OutputStream before switching to the new one.

So, you can abuse the encoder's init method like this:

```cpp
// setup as always
MyAvroStruct obj;
avro::EncoderPtr encoder = avro::binaryEncoder();
std::auto_ptr<avro::OutputStream> out = avro::memoryOutputStream();

// actual serialization
encoder->init(*out);
avro::encode(*encoder, obj);

// re-init on the same OutputStream. Happens to shrink the stream to fit
encoder->init(*out);
size_t bufferSize = out->byteCount();
```

However, this behavior is [not documented](https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.8.1/api/cpp/html/classavro_1_1Encoder.html#a675355be38b2119a1f7472e483267bb3), so it might break in the future.